# Serialize a System.Type from WCF service and deserialize from Silverlight client?

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight-4.0

I am trying to accomplish the task of sending an instance of System.Type from a WCF REST JSON service to a Silverlight client. Although [System.Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) is marked as Serializable, my WCF service responds with a server error if I attempt to have my OperationContract method implementation return a System.Type. For example,

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
                    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                    UriTemplate = "type")]
        public Type getType()
        {
            return typeof(string);
            //request error: The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.
        }
```

I haven't gotten serialization of a System.Type to work with [System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) or DataContractSerializer either. I have only gotten serialization to work with [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx). The problem is, that Silverlight 4 doesn't have BinaryFormatter. I have found [this](http://whydoidoit.com/silverlight-serializer) Silverlight binary serialization library, which looks promising but hasn't succeeded in serializing a System.Type.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to serialize a System.Type from a WCF service and then deserialize it from Silverlight? A code snippet sample of a working solution would be helpful and appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`Type` is not usable in the fashion described (and note that `[Serializable]` only really applies to `BinaryFormatter`). Your best bet is to transport the `AssemblyQualifiedName` and load at each end, but note that you will need the declaring assembly at each end for this to work.

Ultimately the objective of sending a `Type` between platforms doesn't really make much sense, I'm adraid. If you could be more specific a out what you want to *accomplish* maybe we can suggest a better plan?

Comment: The System.DynamicObject doesn't seem to work for data binding in Silverlight, but Types generated at runtime with System.Reflection.Emit do work.

Comment: @TWebster that is not going to work; a nice idea, but not going to work. You could generate an Assembly and send the byte contents, though

Comment: @Marc why won't this work? Why would it be possible to serialize a System.Assembly into bytes, send, and deserialize it, but not a System.Type?

Comment: @TWebster - because you can't serialize a `Type` in the way you are attempting to (hence the question), but an assembly can be saved as a byte-stream (assuming you enable this in your AssemblyBuilder or ModuleBuilder, whichever it is).

Comment: you can't serialize a Type, but would it possibly work to serialize an Assembly, then extract the Type?

Comment: @TWebster yes (as long as the assembly only uses features available at the client) - that is kinda what I said. However, this still screams of unusual design.